# asp.net popup confirmation window

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, popup

I need to add an "are you sure" popup window to a delete button and I am not sure how to get whether the user clicked Ok or Cancel.

Here is how I do it:

```
string message = "Are you sure you want to delete this user?";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("return confirm('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("');");
            Type type = this.GetType();
            ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(type, "alert", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just set OnClientClick on the button to:

```
return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");
```

Then the submit/postback won't happen if the user doesn't click OK.

Comment: @sd_dracula My answer was first, and more importantly if you use this with `CausesValidation="True"` there will be **no** client validation possible on submit, and if you use it with UseSubmitBehavior="False" there will be **no** submit action at all - because JavaScript for these things gets added on Page Render **after** this piece of code, so there is **always** a terminating `return` command which makes it completely unreachable (but in my case only on cancel).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to just add this to your `<input type="button|submit|reset" />` or `<button />` html markup (no submit on cancel): `OnClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;"`

Rename the event to `OnClientClick` for `<asp:Button />` - it is compatible with `CausesValidation="True"` and/or `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`, because it gets added **before** them in the html markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax control toolkit just use the confirmextender

if you want to know wich button the user clicked try this

add a hidden field in your webform

and use this to set his value when the user click Ok

```
  sb.Append("if (confirm(").Append(msg).Append("))")
                .Append("document.getElementById('")
                .Append(confirmResult.ClientID)
                .Append("').value = 'ok';");
```

in your code behind read the value of confirmResult to know if the user clicked ok or cancel

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answers, but in case you don't wanna mix you server and client side code/events then I would suggest you go with AjaxToolKit confirm button http://bit.ly/NtmpOT